# make a field required for a specific profile

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule, isblank, required

I want to make the field deadline required if the user profile is Profile Bs , it not should be empty . (The deadline is a Date ) , but with this code is not working for me , I tried before the trigger to make just a validation rule but also not work for me .

==> The validation rule

```
AND(
($Profile.Name = "Profile Bs"),
ISBLANK(Deadline__c)
)
```

==> The trigger :

```
trigger BeforeInsert on Object1__c (before insert, before update) {

   String profileName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :currentUserProfileId].Name;

    for(Object1__c  ap : trigger.new) 
    {

        if (
            profileName =='Profile Bs'
            )
         {
        
        system.debug('teste');

        if(ap.Deadline__c == null ) 
        {

            ap.Deadline__c.addError('The Deadline is a required field.');
        }
        
        console.log('teste trigger')
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying it with user that his profile match the validation? What profile you get during the trigger try to print it with System.debug(profileName)?

Comment: @ Liron C , yes i tried it with the profile in the validation rule , I use a User  with the same profile in the validation

Comment: Do you need this to operate regardless of how the change is applied - e.g. through the UI but also across REST APIs etc.? If only for the UI, why not have a specific page layout that makes the field mandatory and only assign this page layout to the "Profile Bs" profile?

Comment: If doing it in the trigger, why not do this by testing the profile ID, `Id profileBsId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Profile Bs'];` then simply have a single test to see if the `if (UserInfo.getProfileId() == profileBsId)` and only if it does then perform the iteration of `Trigger.new` to add errors where `Deadline__c` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always have problems checking Profile Names in Validation Rules, what works for me is Custom Permissions.
Is simply a Flag (true or false) and you can add any profile to that Permisison.
In the Validation rule you can check if the profile of the user have that flag this way:

`$Permission.Name_of_permission = False`

I use this solution with System Administrator to leave it out of the Validation and let admins able to change whatever the validation is checking.